# returning only specific rows in a .csv file python

Tags: python, pandas

In my .csv file, I have 32 rows, but I only want it to return 10 rows out of those 32. So if I want to return rows 2, 7, 12, 13, 14, 17, 27, 29, 30, 32, how would I go about doing that?

I have:

```
read_poem_data = pd.read_csv('poem_data.csv')
print(read_poem_data.loc[2:3])
```

but this is only printing lines 2 and 3 of my file, when i want it to print 10 specific lines remove all the other lines from my .csv file.

---

Comment: `read_poem_data.loc[[(line-1) for line in [2, 7, 12, 13, 14, 17, 27, 29, 30, 32]]]` (because row #1 has the index of 0, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2:3 slices the data and gives you the rows 2 and 3. You have to provide all the rows you need like this

```
df1 = read_poem_data.loc[[2, 7, 12, 13, 14, 17, 27, 29, 30, 32]]
```

To get it back in csv,

```
df1.to_csv('poem_data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thanks! and how would i go about removing all the unecessary rows from my .csv file?

Comment: @emptybladder [Write the file back](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) without those rows.